# View for Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe board

Tags: html, css, game, community-challenge

I've put together a board for *Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe* ([What's that?](http://bejofo.net/ttt)). This is part of the current [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge): [**Code a Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1472/35408)

**Resources:**

- [Live demo of my view](https://jsfiddle.net/jLqru90z/) – For you to see what I did there
- [Simon's working implementation](http://www.zomis.net/ttt/TTTWeb.html) – To illustrate that this is going to be a functional game

**Questions:**

- What are your thoughts on the Markup? Overkill? Just right?
- What would you improve on the CSS side? Especially asking in the direction of absolute dimensions and borders.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="game">
    <div class="area area-0-0">
        <div class="tile tile-0-0">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-1-0">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-2-0">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-0-1">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-1-1">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-2-1">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-0-2">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-1-2">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-2-2">
            <button type="button" class="tile-button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area area-1-0">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
    <div class="area area-2-0">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
    <div class="area area-0-1">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
    <div class="area area-1-1">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
    <div class="area area-2-1">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
    <div class="area area-0-2">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
    <div class="area area-1-2">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
    <div class="area area-2-2">
        <!-- 9 tiles -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}



/*
 *  GAME
 *  Board size is calculated as follows:
 *
 *  .game = .area * 3
 *  459px = 153px * 3
 *
 *  .area = padding-left + .tile * 3 + padding-right + border
 *  153px = 3px          + 48px  * 3 + 3px           + 3px
 *
 *  .tile = padding-left + .width    + padding-right
 *   48px = 3px          + 42px      + 3px
 */
.game {
    width: 459px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

/* Clearfixing .game */
.game:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .game {
        width: 315px;
    }
}



/*
 *  AREA
 */
.area {
    float: left;
    width: 153px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.area:nth-child(3n-1),
.area:nth-child(3n-0) {
    border-left: 3px solid #444;
}

.area:nth-child(4),
.area:nth-child(5),
.area:nth-child(6),
.area:nth-child(7),
.area:nth-child(8),
.area:nth-child(9) {
    border-top: 3px solid #444;
}

/* Clearfixing .area */
.area:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .area {
        width: 105px;
    }
}



/*
 *  TILE
 */
.tile {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
}



/*
 *  BUTTONS
 */
.tile-button {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;

    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: greenYellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .tile-button {
        width: 26px;
        height: 26px;
    }
}

.tile-button:hover,
.tile-button:focus {
    border-color: #444;
    background-color: yellowGreen;
}
```

Comment: Looking back at this I can't help but think, this must be possible to do with CSS-grid these days...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks good. I like the way it adapts to smaller windows.

I'm not sure why (except as an aretfact of styling) you have a div around each button; maybe the button alone would do.

Instead of using divs it might be possible/appropriate to use tables instead.

You haven't demonstrated (although Simon's game does demonstrate) how you intend to mark played buttons with an O or X; nor how to draw a line through won games. I'd find it easier if X and O were different colors (e.g. blue and red to reflect the colors you chose for won games); and I don't like the `font-size: small` used in your clean.css.

To draw a (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal) line through won games, maybe make the buttons semi-transparent so that the line can be a CSS background.

When a quadrant is unplayable (because the opponent played elsewhere), do you still intend to draw buttons in that quadrant, or something else?

Do you need to do anything to adjust the apparent size on a 'retina' (double-density-pixel) display?

Does each button need a name attribute and should they be embedded in a form? Or will you be adding javascript?

Maybe make the index 1-based (1 through 9) instead of 0 based (0 through 8). Have you thought about [accessibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) (e.g. someone using a screen-reader)?

Maybe supply the game state in JSON as well as HTML, so that a bot that's playing (e.g. perhaps a Greasemonkey script) doesn't need to scrape the HTML to discover the game state.

Why are you using px instead of em or % to specify CSS dimensions?

Comment: I used an additional `div` around the control element (`button` in my version) to have better control over thinks like padding/margin. We discussed the table-topic in the chat. We want the table only for the easier layout handling. Therefor we wanted to use `div`'s instead. Also, it's a Code __Challenge__. :p

Comment: I'm only doing the view for Simon's __working__ game, because I'm not a programmer. The `clean.css` you refer to is some generated stuff from Simon's game, not mine. I don't like it either. I will discuss your questions in the chat. Also we agreed on using 0 through 8 based indexing to mirror the logic. I'd prefer 1 through 9, tho.

Comment: X and O in different colors, that I LIKE! Technically, the buttons require neither names nor specific CSS classes for the logic to work as I've made my implementation in GWT (Google Web Toolkit) and GWT keeps references to the buttons when they are added dynamically. I like the idea of JSON! I don't see what good 1-based indexes would make?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg 1-based is perhaps a dumb idea, for the human reader (if any) not for the browser. I can 'visualize' the location when it's only 0..2, but it's harder with `0..8`. More important UI-related comments were IMO perhaps not using `px`, displaying lines (perhaps through translucent buttons).

Answer (score 10):

The one thing I see here that's absolutely unnecessary is the use of the button element.  If you're using event delegation properly (I can't tell by looking at the functional version since it's obfuscated), all you should need is a single event handler attached to the game board.  Just check to see if your event's target element is a `tile` and make adjustments as necessary to the tile's attributes or child nodes.

Game boards are one areas where I believe that it is appropriate to use tables, even though it feels like you would be using them for layout.  If you consider a game like Chess, the tiles are all named (A1-H8).  The use of tables would actually simplify some of your CSS, since you would be able to make use of properties like `border-spacing: 5px` to get those nice gaps between your individual board tiles.

The naming conventions you've chosen for your tiles' class names leads me to believe that you're using JavaScript to parse their positions.  I recommend using `data-*` attributes instead:

```
<div class="tile" data-row="1" data-col="1"></div>
<div class="tile" data-row="1" data-col="2"></div>
```

Here's a demo that illustrates some of these ideas for a card game (the interactivity is there, but the gameplay isn't):  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/lKgpJ

Comment: I'm doing the view for Simon's game, but not the logic. I'm not a programmer. Thank you for your suggestions. I will consider these. Sounds good to me.

Comment: GWT (Google Web Toolkit) takes care of all the JavaScript stuff for me. It **compiles** my Java code to JavaScript. Therefore, your JS suggestion doesn't help me :) I like the idea of `data-row` instead of the class names though (technically I don't even need all the class names, as GWT automatically keeps references to the elements when they are added). As for the CSS, I let @kleinfreund decide on that :)

Answer (score 8):

You can simplify this

```
.area:nth-child(4),
.area:nth-child(5),
.area:nth-child(6),
.area:nth-child(7),
.area:nth-child(8),
.area:nth-child(9) {
    border-top: 3px solid #444;
}
```

to

```
.area:nth-child(n + 4) {
    border-top: 3px solid #444;
}
```

Since you are calculating the dimensions according to the game, and later setting media-queries, it will make it more easy to set

```
area {
    width: 33%;
}

and 

tile {
    width: 28%;
    padding 2%;
}
```

or something in this line. Then, you don't need to worry to get your queries in sync.

Comment: I was using `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` in earlier versions and had problems with the the calculated dimensions on mobile devices. So for the first working demo I stuck to pixels. I will use percentages in the next version. Thank you. :)

Comment: As for the multiple `.area` selectors, I agree that didn't look very optimal, I think I will apply specific class names such as `has-top-border` and `has-left-border` and apply those dynamically from my GWT (Google Web Toolkit) code.